# How do I match multiple fields to only part of a query string in a mongoose query?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

Let's say I have a collection of books that contains multiple documents that looks like this:

```
{
    "author":"Gud Author",
    "title":"Gud Book"
}
{
    "author":"Lazy Writer",
    "title":"Lesson about lazyness"
}
{
    "author":"Mysterious Enigma",
    "title":"Ways of the unknown"
}
```

In the request I'm getting one query parameter (string) called "filter". I want to use this parameter to get only the books whose author or title matches at least a part of the filter string.
This is my code so far:

```
bookRouter.get("/books", (req,res) => {
  const {filter} = req.query
  let query = {}
  if (filter) query.$or = [{author: {$regex: filter}}, {title: {$regex: filter}}]
  Book.find(query)
    .then((books) => res.json(books))
    .catch((err) => res.json(err))
})
```

If the filter parameter is shorter than the values in my db everything works ok.
"" as filter would return everything,
"Gud" would only return the first object
"Mysterious" would only return the third object"

However when my query is " Mysterious Enigma Ways" I'm getting back an empty array. Also a combination of both title and author that is only a partial match with both db values like "Mysterious Ways" won't work.

How do i modify my query to also return documents that only match with a part of the query string?

I've tried turning the string into an array (separating words) using `.join(" ")` to compare matches to the single elements of the array but I couldn't figure out how to combine the operators for this query.

PS: Yes I will convert both query string and values to lowercase for case-insensitive comparison. Just wanted to keep this short.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$regex`, try using plain Javascript regex, by splitting the input words and checking if any of the words are present using `$in`,

```
let splitWords = filter.split(" ");

let regexWords = splitWords.map(e =>{return new RegExp(e,i)}

if (filter) query.$or = [{author: {$in: regexWords}}, {title: {{$in: regexWords}}]
```